# part of text over image html

Tags: html, css, text

I have this situation:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgBdX.jpg

and I would that part of text also occupied the area circled with red. It is possible?
The code of the image and the text is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<b>In tutte le varianti ITT si attiva grazie ai 
Tag.</b> Questa dotazione consente al sistema di rilevare la presenza di 
personale all’interno dell'area di pericolo dell'impianto ed evitare 
tutti i tipi di collisioni possibili. Nello specifico i macchinari 
possono essere dotati di un Tablet touch-screen che fornisce informazioni 
relative alla posizione dell’ostacolo rilevato rispetto al mezzo e alla 
sua direzione di marcia. In più la rilevazione di tutte le informazioni 
relative agli individui che sono entrati in contatto con la safety cloud 
(o area di pericolo) potranno essere registrate e rielaborate per 
migliorare il livello di sicurezza del reparto produttivo.</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<img src="images/stories/Prodotti/ITT_Interactive_Tracking_Tags/itt_safety_securi
  ty/ITT_Factory_simulation.jpg" alt="itt map safety security" />
</div>
</div>
```

The image in the code is jpg, but I can make a png transparent image.
Thanks!

Comment: You can do it, but it is very complicated. You will need to position the image absolutely above the text (assuming that area is transparent, otherwise you have to put it behind the text) and then you need to add `div`s where you want the text to stop and wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is divide the content into two `<div>s`. The bottom `<div>` will overflow because it has a width of `>100%` parent width. Set the image `z-index` to a lower value than the `z-index` of the `overlapping div` and the text will go over the image.

Try this:

```css
.topText
{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   color:#000;
   border:1px solid #09f;
}

.bottomText
{
   position:relative;
   float:left;
   width:150%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   color:#000;
   border:1px solid #09f;
   overflow:visible;
   z-index:2;
}

div img
{
   z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="topText"><b>In tutte le varianti ITT si attiva grazie ai Tag.</b><p>Questa dotazione consente al sistema di rilevare la presenza di personale all’interno dell'area di pericolo dell'impianto ed evitare tutti i tipi di collisioni possibili. Nello specifico i macchinari possono essere dotati di un Tablet touch-screen che fornisce informazioni relative alla posizione dell’ostacolo rilevato rispetto al mezzo e alla sua direzione di marcia.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomText">
        <p>In più la rilevazione di tutte le informazioni relative agli individui che sono entrati in contatto con la safety cloud (o area di pericolo) potranno essere registrate erielaborate per migliorare il livello di sicurezza del reparto produttivo..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="https://static.rogerebert.com/redactor_assets/pictures/rogers-journal/the-republicans-exit-history/_20_20_20consumer-thumb-280x310-37393.jpg" alt="Sample image" width="100%" height="auto" />
   <div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Mmm no, the text over the image would be part of the text of the left, not another block of text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but I think if you add `<br>` tags where you want the text to go on the next line, it might work. But if the image is a square, then it might not work, unless the text can go over the image.

Comment: *But if the image is a square*... Hmmm, are there images of different shapes than square or rectangle?

Comment: There are circles, if you style it, but I'm not sure if it's just for looks, but if you inspect it, it might be a square...

Comment: I'm agree with @RacilHilan

Comment: You would need css, and add the following:
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

See more here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_rounded_images.asp

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. Using CSS does not alter the image. It looks round, but it still occupies rectangular space, so the text flows around it the same way with or without the CSS. See [Fabien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043927/3215948), that's the kind of CSS that forces the text to flow around shapes other than rectangles.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. It only makes it look like a circle/

Answer (score 0):

If there's no need to be responsive, you could make text container's `position:absolute` and use `<br>` to break rows where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is CSS shapes, but it's [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-shapes).
Take a look at [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/) about how to use it, and [this library](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill) to have it on other browsers.

Comment: Yes, CSS shapes are what the OP needs... Wish the support was better, but until then, creating the effect manually is pretty complex.